# CASE dentro de un cursor en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo este evento en el que quiero comprobar todos los días si las fechas de los torneos (son varios) están antes, entre o después de la fecha actual.
Me explico: cada torneo tiene fecha inicio y fecha fin, y también tienen un "estado":
1->abierto (la fecha actual está entre la fecha inicio y la fecha fin),
2->cerrado (la fecha actual es mayor que la fecha fin) y
3->futuro (la fecha actual es menos que la fecha inicio).

Lo que quiero es cada día comprobar dichas fechas para que, por ejemplo, si un torneo ya ha finalizado hacerle un update del "estado" a 2. Debido a que tengo que ir haciéndolo uno a uno supongo que la opción correcta será hacerlo con un cursor, y luego dentro de ese cursor he hecho un case para cada situación relacionado con las fechas. Mi duda es si la sintaxis del case está bien, en concreto la parte de `fechaInicio<curdate()<fechaFin`.
Aparte si ustedes ven algún otro fallo no duden en decírmelo, cualquier crítica constructiva es bienvenida.

Código:

```sql
delimiter $$
create event checkTorneos on schedule every day do
begin 

    declare idTorneo int;
    declare fechaInicio date;
    declare fechaFin date;
    declare fin int default false;
    
    declare cursorTorneos cursor for select id_torneo,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin from torneo;
    declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;
    
    open cursor;
        bucle: loop
            fetch cursorTorneos into idTorneo,fechaInicio,fechaFin;
            if fin then
                leave bucle;
            end if;
            
            case
                when fechaInicio>curdate() then update torneo set estado=3 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
                when fechaFin<curdate() then update torneo set estado=2 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
                when fechaInicio<curdate()<fechaFin then update torneo set estado=1 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
            end;
        end loop bucle;
    close cursorTorneos;
end;

delimiter $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto para la parte del código que preguntas sería:

```
when fechaInicio <= curdate() and fechaFin <= curdate() then update torneo 
set estado = 1 where id_torneo = idTorneo;
```

No solo debes comparar si es menor, también debes comparar si es igual, tanto para la fechaInicio como para fechaFin, y para hacer dos condiciones en sql se usa **and** que indica que la condicion de la izquierda como la de la derecha se deben cumplir.

Pero en este caso solo hay 3 situaciones que se pueden dar y si ya comparaste cuando es menor y cuando es mayor lo que te queda es el caso que no sea ninguno de esto, para eso puedes usar el **else** dentro del case, de esta forma:

```
case
    when fechaInicio>curdate() then update torneo set estado=3 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
    when fechaFin<curdate() then update torneo set estado=2 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
    else update torneo set estado = 1 where id_torneo = idTorneo; update torneo set estado=1 where id_torneo=idTorneo;
end;
```

Para optimizar el código:

```
declare cursorTorneos cursor for select 
id_torneo,fecha_inicio,fecha_fin from torneo
where estado <> 2;
```

Agregar un where ya que si el estado ya está cerrado no necesitas verificarlo, solo los abiertos y futuros son los que te interesan.